# Navigating between two viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I have set my initial **ViewController** as `rootViewController` in `appDelegate` because I don't use storyboard. It looks like this way:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var mainNavigationController: UINavigationController?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.mainNavigationController = UINavigationController()
    var mainController: UIViewController? = TineLineViewController()
    self.mainNavigationController!.pushViewController(mainController!, animated: true)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = mainController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
     ...
       ...
```

My application running and my `TineLineViewController` shows up.

I have in this class a UIButton which call this method:

```
  func postLeft(_sender: AnyObject?)
    {
        println("go to secound view..")
        let secondViewController = PostCreateController()

        let appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        self.navigationController?.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = secondViewController
    }
```

This way if I push the button the screen change and my `secondViewController` shows up, without animation...

If I try to change the view this way:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

It's still don't have any animations and after the `secoundViewController` shows up my application crash with this message:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller  as a child of view controller:'
*** First throw call stack:
(

I don't know if is it a best way to set my `rootviewController` class in `appDelagate` and why can't navigate without adding this line to my potLeft function:

```
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = secondViewController
```

Without this line I can see in my app consol, the `secondViewController` `viewDidLoad` method is called, but the controller not shows up, and I get this message to the cosole:

Warning: **Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

How to navigate between two view without use storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Set mainNavigationController to rootViewController
2) Use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)`

**Explanation**

Logically your root view controller is UINavigationController while you are setting TineLineViewController to app's delegate rootViewController property. That is why you're getting exception.

```
self.mainNavigationController = UINavigationController()
var mainController: UIViewController? = TineLineViewController()
self.mainNavigationController!.pushViewController(mainController!, animated: true)
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
// ERROR is here
// self.window!.rootViewController = mainController

// your root view controller should be navigation controller
self.window!.rootViewController = mainNavigationController

self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `secondViewController` as `rootViewController` of the `navigationController` with animation:

```
func postLeft(_sender: AnyObject?)
{
    println("go to secound view..")
    let secondViewController = PostCreateController()

    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([secondViewController], animated: true)
}
```

Hope this have helped you !

Comment: thank you, i tried this but nothing happens.. :( the secoundViewController doesn't shows up.. :(

Comment: Did you check the `self.navigationController` is nil?

Comment: println(self.navigationController) = Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7fb5bbc507d0>)

Comment: self.window!.rootViewController = self.mainNavigationController

Comment: println(self.navigationController)
        println(self.view.window!.rootViewController)
Optional(<UINavigationController: 0x7fcceac19c50>)
Optional(<KallerRadar.TineLineViewController: 0x7fcceac1eae0>)
So they ar not equals

Comment: Yeah, but they should be equals

Comment: hmm, and why could this be?

Comment: Instead of using `self.window!.rootViewController = mainController`, you should use `self.window!.rootViewController = self.mainNavigationController`.